# Windows 7 Batch file to turn off firewall and restart computer

Tags: windows-7, batch, firewall

I'm trying to create a batch file to do as the title states. Currently, I have:

`netsh advfirewall set allprofiles state off`

`sleep 30`

`C:\windows\system32\shutdown -r -t 00`

This batch file restarts the computer but it doesn't shut down the firewall.

Should the service be set to manual prior to running the batch file?

Comment: You mean it turns it off before the restart and it is back on after the restart?

Comment: Are you running `netsh advfirewall ...` with Admin permissions?

Comment: @DavidPostill - 1. I can't verify that the firewall is being turned off as the computer restarts right away after the script executes. 2 - I'm running the batch script with "Run as Administrator".

Comment: Can you run `netsh advfirewall set allprofiles state off` and then run `netsh advfirewall show currentprofile` from a command line? **Don't restart**. The second command should show `State OFF` if the first one worked.

Comment: Then restart manually and run `netsh advfirewall show currentprofile` again from a command line? Is it now `ON` or `OFF`?

Comment: @DavidPostill my problem is that I'm doing this remotely from a different computer. (I.E. I'm logging into one computer (remote software) and executing batch script remotely via CMD. If I turn off firewall, the second computer crashes and I cannot login without a physical reset on-site.

Comment: So please [edit] your question and include this **new** information. It apppears you are asking the **wrong question**. You should be asking something like "Why does the remote computer crash if I turn off the firewall". Your current question **does not mention a remote computer** where all these commands are being run.

Comment: And please include some information **about the crash**. How does it crash? Are there any error messages? What are they? What is in the event log?

Comment: @DavidPostill - I apologize for lack of clarity but my question is the same - I just can't physically test your suggestion. From the script that I included, it should work but I believe that `netsh` is not executing prior to restart. Crashing computer is unrelated to this (its how the physical location is setup). This is also with regard to a POS terminals/server so including that information would be lengthy and not contribute.

Comment: @DavidPostill - the computer doesn't crash, my remote connection crashes and I need a physical on-site restart to get the connection going.

Comment: You can still do what I suggested above. Can you `run netsh advfirewall set allprofiles state off` and then `run netsh advfirewall show currentprofile` from a command line? Don't restart. The second command should show `State OFF` if the first one worked.

Comment: This will help to clarify your problem/

Answer (score 0):

So after some fiddling I found that even if you turn of windows firewall using `netsh advfirewall`, and restart the computer, the windows firewall service will automatically start it.

In order for it to work, I had to set windows firewall service to manual then re-run the script, which turned off the firewall and restarted without issues.

Thank you @DavidPostill for helping out with this.